# run matlab scripts in parallel from macos terminal

Tags: bash, matlab, shell, terminal, gnu-parallel

Let's suppose I have 4 folders into a directory and each folder contains a `matlab` script `example.m`.

I want to run these scripts using `GNU parallel` from a macos terminal.

I correctly installed `GNU parallel` as per http://macappstore.org/parallel/ and tried the following from the terminal:

```
parallel ::: */example.m
```

but I get the following errors:

> /bin/bash: 1/example.m: Permission denied
>
> /bin/bash: 2/example.m: Permission denied
>
> /bin/bash: 3/example.m: Permission denied
>
> /bin/bash: 4/example.m: Permission denied

what is missing?
shall the script(s) to be run by `parallel` be in the `.sh` format?

Comment: `example1.m` is not a bash command. The error means that the file in question doesn’t have the execute bit set (I.e. is not executable). You need to run MATLAB explicitly.

Comment: thanks. I tried...see question update

Comment: What does “it does not work” mean? Please describe what happens. You might need to first `cd` into the directory, then execute `example`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have never run MatLab.

If you can run:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2019a.app/bin/matlab -singleCompThread -nojvm -r "run('example1.m');exit;"
```

Then try this:

```
parallel --dry-run -q /Applications/MATLAB_R2019a.app/bin/matlab -singleCompThread -nojvm -r "run('{}');exit;" ::: */example*.m
```

If the lines it prints out look correctly, remove `--dry-run` from the command line and run it without `--dry-run`:

```
parallel -q /Applications/MATLAB_R2019a.app/bin/matlab -singleCompThread -nojvm -r "run('{}');exit;" ::: */example*.m
```

Comment: hi, the first command works fine but instead of -nojvm I had to use -nodesktop. the parallel version of it does not work.

Comment: Maybe it wants a terminal? Try adding `-u`: `parallel -u`.

Comment: no...I get this: /Applications/MATLAB_R2019a.app/bin/matlab -singleCompThread -nodesktop -r 'run('"'"'1/example.m'"'"');exit;'